# Select query showing wrong result

Tags: java, mysql

I am tring to check whether a data is available or not in database table.if not it will insert the data. But in first button click it works perfectly. by when i try to click the button again with the same value  it gets inserted into the table. please help someone

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Object obj[] = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cem?useSSL=false", "root", "123");
        //here stu is database name, root is username and password
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String pn = "select gname from games where gname='" + jTextField1.getText() + "'";
        ResultSet rsPn = stmt.executeQuery(pn);
        System.out.println(rsPn.next());
        if (rsPn.next() == false) {

            String q = ("insert into games(gid,gname) values(NULL,'" + jTextField1.getText() + "')");
            int i = 0;
            i = stmt.executeUpdate(q);
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.println("success");
                list.add(jTextField1.getText());
                obj = list.toArray();
                model.addRow(obj);

            } else {
                System.out.println("stuck somewhere");

            }

            StudentDetails.details();
            jTextField1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } else {
            jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
            System.out.println("Name Already exist");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InsertPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InsertPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have a unique key on `gname`?

Comment: This code is a bad idea.  You should never mingle UI and database code together this way.  It's an untestable mess.  Better to write a repository class that you can test and put aside, giving a reference to the controller class.  The repository class should load the result set into a collection and return it to the calling method.  You way is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `next()` twice:

```
System.out.println(rsPn.next());
if (rsPn.next() == false) {
```

The second call will return `false` even if there's a row already (though it should work once there are two or more rows). Use a variable instead:

```
boolean hasNext = rdPn.next();
System.out.println(hasNext);
if (!hasNext) {
```